# Is it better to redirect root to www or www to root?

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, redirect, web, 301-redirect

This may be a 'fashion' question, but is it better to redirect:

https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
or
https://example.com -> https://www.example.com?

I always assumed it was better to have people bookmark the www site instead of the TLD root, to save lookups to the root (as that's mixed in with MX records and other lookups).

I've noticed some browsers 'hide' the www prefex, and insert it if there's no response on the root, so users may not even be aware nowadays.

Which way is better and why? Does it really matter?

I am not asking 'how' - I know how to do this either way - I'm asking 'why' and 'which way'.

In the 'early days' you were encouraged to use [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), but things change ...

Comment: In my opinion, it's better to not redirect at all.

Comment: So people going to the root get nothing? Or

Comment: No, you host the website just on both domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `www.` prefix is a remnant from the glorious old 90s when you had a single machine for each service, like FTP, WWW, SMTP etc. and had to use a separate hostname for each one. The apex/bare domain usually went for an SMTP server as the apex was historically used for email before the invention of WWW.

Nowadays, everything is WWW. Browsers dropped support for protocols other than HTTP/HTTPS. Everyone is typing `example.com` into their address bars, not `www.example.com`, especially on their phones/tablets. It is painful to pronounce `www` in English. From the UX point of view, the `www.` prefix is atavism and was considered archaic even in 2010 - see [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109356/www-or-not-www-what-to-choose-as-primary-site-name).

From the technical point of view, there are no such limitations such as "You can only have a single A and/or AAAA record at the apex/null/bare domain". There are no technical standards imposing such limitations. You can find multiple A/AAAA records on such domains as `microsoft.com`, `amazon.com`, `netfix.com`, `cloudflare.com` etc. Unless my memory fails me, Google also used to have multiple addresses for their services in the past.

There is one technical limitation with the apex domain. You can't have CNAME as the apex RR which limits the use of CDNs or platform hosting services which want your domain to be a CNAME pointing to their service domain. You need to host your DNS with these services in order to use such services with your apex domain. If you want to use CloudFlare, you need to use their DNS with CNAME flattening. If you want to use AWS CloudFront, you need to use their Route53 DNS with ALIAS records.

From SEO point of view, there is no difference between `www.example.com`
and `example.com` as long as you have only one of them as a canonical URL and redirect another to the canonical one (or embed `link rel=canonical` but this is going to create a mess in a browser history). But once you select one and start redirecting, you can't go the other way later because `301` redirects `Moved Permanently` are stored by browsers forever. That is why the old sites like `google.com`, `microsoft.com`, `apple.com` etc. are stuck with `www.` prefix.

Chrome tries to fix this mess by hiding `www.` prefix in the UI. There are no browsers that add `www.` on their own unless there is a redirect from the bare domain. The use of `www.` prefix as a canonical URL adds unnecessary redirects for most users who prefer to type a shorter bare domain.

I would recommend using a bare domain unless you need a CNAME for some service but this service doesn't provide its own DNS (or has some features missing in their DNS) or if you can't move DNS to this service for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for the very complete discussion. Cheerfully upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a single A and/or AAAA record at the apex/null/bare domain. That's rather restrictive (you can't do RR-DNS, geo-aware DNS becomes tricky). Since modern browsers will automatically add the 'www.' to something you type in the address bar, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) should be the canonical name.

Comment: Can you give a reference to an RFC that prohibits multiple A/AAAA records for the apex? Can you add a reference that modern browsers automatically add the 'www.' to something you type in the address bar?

Comment: `serverfault.com` has two A (but zero AAAA) on apex and works fine. (Same for `superuser.com stackoverflow.com stackexchange.com` unsurprisingly.)

Comment: Can't find a reference off the top of my head - and it does indeed *appear* that some stackoverflow sites have multiple sites. Historically bind would not prevent you configuring stuff this way but a few years ago I found several providers would not permit this (and confirmed the specs at that time). This may have changed. But even if that's the case, that doesn't mean every provider implements this.

Comment: Google Bard agrees with me: "DNS Standard: The Domain Name System (DNS) standard, RFC 1035, explicitly forbids multiple A records for the apex domain. This restriction ensures consistency and avoids ambiguity in resolving the root of a domain."

Comment: @symcbean, are you aware that LLMs hallucinate a lot? RFC 1035 doesn't say anything close to "explicitly forbid multiple A records for the apex domain".

Comment: Yes. Doesn't mean they are not sometimes right. You might wnat to explain to names.co.uk and 123-reg that you think they should allow this.

Comment: @symcbean, some registrars' behaviour doesn't define internet standards. The internet standards are defined by RFCs and there is nothing in RFCs that prohibits the use of multiple A/AAAA records for the apex.

Comment: Neither do the comments of random people on the internet. I really can't be bothered trailing through lots of RFCs just to demonstrate who is being ignorant here. If your NS provider lets you do this great. But if you subsequently decide to change providers, good luck.

Comment: Amazon, Google, GoDaddy - all allow multiple A/AAAA records. And as you haven't bothered yourself with providing any evidence that this is prohibited by RFC as I asked in my first comment, I suspect that you haven't bothered yourself with verifying that your statements are true with the NS providers you mentioned.

Comment: Can confirm that `names.co.uk` control panel allowed multiple A records for an apex domain at least in 2018.